# Graphing a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I have a question about graphing a polynomial. I don't know how to find the zeros, asimptote and other information to graph the following polynomial: $$\lvert(x^2(x+3)-10x-24)\rvert$$

How to factorize the polynomial and how to find all other information. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Plot: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7C+(x%5E2(x%2B3)-10x-24)%7C

Comment: Factor: $$\left| (x-3) (x+2) (x+4)\right|$$

Comment: Let $f(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 - 10x -24$.  Since $-24$ has factors $\pm 1, \pm 2, \dots$, and $f(0) < 0 < f(6)$, try
$$f(3) = 3^3+3^3-10(3)-24 = 18 \cdot 3 - (10 + 8) \cdot 3 = 0.$$
Therefore, $x-3$ is a factor of $f(x)$.  Use short division to obtain $f(x) = (x-3) (x^2+6x+8) = (x-3)(x-2)(x-4)$.

Comment: You ask for asymptotes but **polynomials don't have asymptotes** (even when taken with absolute values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

Focus on the polynomial inside the absolute sign.

$$p(x)=x^3+3x^2-10x-24$$

By rational root test (try out factors of $24$), we can see that $x=-2$ is a root and hence $(x+2)$ is a factor of the polynomial. Hence we can write $p(x)=(x+2)q(x)$ where $q(x)$ is a quadratic function.

After finding out the root of $p(x)$, note that $\lim_{x \to \infty} p(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} p(x)=-\infty.$

With that you can sketch $p(x)$, to sketch $|p(x)|$, if you see $p(x)$ take negative value, flip the graph to make it positive.

Comment: How do you get the quadratic equation form?

Comment: divide $p(x)$ by $x+2$. If you try all the factors of $24$, you can also find all the roots for this question too.